# Monte Carlo approximation of the integral of y=2^(-0.5)x from 0 to 1 boolean isn't working properly

Tags: java, math, boolean, do-while, montecarlo

[Professor's equation for the boolean condition that satisfies "hitPointsCounter" in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhU2X.png)

In a Java class I'm tasked with solving several Monte Carlo approximations for geometric area.  My first experiment with this I have a boolean called "conditional" running a do-while loop that is satisfied when (error < tolerance) - as of now when I run my program this seems to be yielding an infinite loop.

When I change my "while" statement from the boolean to a counter I can get it to run properly, so I know there's an issue with the boolean itself.

The condition that my professor gave me for incrementing my hitPointsCounter variable would work well if I was asked to solve for the area of the square with height 2^(-0.5) from 0 to 1, but not with the equation y=2^(-0.5)x - so I improvised and noticed that for a point to be on or under the line it must be satisfied by x/y >= 2^0.5.

Could anyone give me some feedback for where I may have screwed up?  My issue is somewhere between the switch case 1: and break.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){




    double tolerance = 1E-9, referenceArea =0.0, exactArea =0.0, x =0.0,     y =0.0, error = 0.0, approximateArea = 0.0;
    int  totalPointsCounter =0, hitPointsCounter =0;
    char firstCharacter ;
    String titleText, messageText;

    titleText = "The Monte Carlo Method";

    int userInput = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Run a Monte Carlo Experiment?", titleText, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (userInput == 1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The program terminates \nGood Bye!", titleText,  JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0);

    }


    String userExperimentInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter\n1 for Experiment 1\n2 for Experiment 2\n3 for Experiment 3\n4 for Experiment 4", titleText,  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE).trim();

      if(userExperimentInput == null || userExperimentInput.equals("") ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No input received\nThe program terminates", titleText,  JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);     
      }
char theCase = userExperimentInput.charAt(0);



switch (theCase){
    case '1': 
        exactArea = Math.pow(2, -0.5)*1/2; 
        referenceArea = 1.0;


         boolean condition = error < tolerance;

         double percentHit = (((double)hitPointsCounter/(double)totalPointsCounter));
   approximateArea =(percentHit)*(referenceArea);
error = exactArea - Math.abs(approximateArea);

int counter = 0;

do {
        x= Math.random();
        y= Math.random();
        totalPointsCounter++;

        if (y==0 && x==0){hitPointsCounter++;}
        if (y>0){
        if ((x/y)>=Math.pow(2, 0.5)){

                hitPointsCounter++;}
        }

        exactArea = Math.pow(2, -0.5)*1/2; 
        referenceArea = 1.0;




        counter++;

        }

while(condition);

  percentHit = (((double)hitPointsCounter/(double)totalPointsCounter));
   approximateArea =(percentHit)*(referenceArea);
error = exactArea - Math.abs(approximateArea);



messageText ="Experiment #1" + ": \n\nMC needed " + totalPointsCounter + " random points for tolerance " + tolerance + "\nThe approximate area is " + approximateArea;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messageText, titleText, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

break;



    case 2: 
        exactArea = Math.PI;
        referenceArea = 4.0;







    case 3:
        exactArea = (1.0/3.0);
        referenceArea = 2.0;







    case 4:
        exactArea = 2;
        referenceArea = Math.PI;





    default: 
        System.out.println("Wrong character for case number, program terminates");
        System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer but I would venture to guess that the loop is infinite because nothing is updating the `condition` variable within the loop. Also keep in mind that using a `do ... while` loop means that the code block is going to be executed at least once, regardless of the condition - make sure this is what you want.

Comment: You're right, that's a big part of my problem.  I've found another problem that I would have run into even had I fixed that though: my approach to defining hitPointsCounter as (x/y) >= sqrt(2) wasn't allowing me to get within my tolerance level for error.  

I talked to my professor and he just left an 'x' out of the boolean equation on the pic.  So it's y<Math.pow(2, -0.5)*x (Duh).  Yesterday I was groggy and had a hard time thinking straight to code.  I'll get more work done on it after class today and see if I can't post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So i got the code to work, the issue was twofold - my code wasn't reevaluating the boolean 'condition' within the loop causing an infinite loop and the way I defined hitPointCounter previously wasn't correct.  Thank you Damon for your help.  When I added this block:

```
           percentHit =   (((double)hitPointsCounter/(double)totalPointsCounter));
           approximateArea =(percentHit)*(referenceArea);
           error = Math.abs(exactArea - approximateArea);
           condition = error > tolerance;
```

within my loop and changed

```
     if (y==0 && x==0){hitPointsCounter++;}
     if (y>0){
     if ((x/y)>=Math.pow(2, 0.5)){

            hitPointsCounter++;}
    }
```

to:

```
if (y<(Math.pow(2,-0.5)*x)){

                hitPointsCounter++;}
```

The code worked like a charm.